# Can anyone tell me what tree does this leaf belong to?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found a lovely tree in my friends yard and we do not have a clue what tree is it. The leaf texture is a but like the ginko biloba, but the shape is different. Can anyone identify it? (It's in Romania, Eastern Europe, but I suspect it's not a local tree)
[image]

Comment: definitely looks like ***Liriodendron tulipifera*** (aka tulip tree, tulip poplar, yellow poplar)

Answer (score 4):

maybe it is from [tulip-tree (Liriodendron tulipifera)](http://www.tree-guide.com/tulip-tree)

use one of this applications to identify plant species:

1. http://www.plantsnapp.com/#theapp
2. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id957861141?mt=8
3. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/flowerchecker-plant-identification/id916709270?mt=8
4. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.thran.flowercheckerplus

and many others [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gardening/tools-and-accessories/the-best-apps-to-identify-unknown-plants-and-flowers/)